# How to run Sprint boot Web application on Java 1.6

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, maven-3

I am working on a web project that using **spring boot** and maven.I am able to run my application on **JAVA 1.8** successfully but when i try it to run on **JAVA 1.6** i am facing issues.

My **POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>Demo_Web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Demo_Web</name>
    <description>Demo_Web</description>
    <!-- <url> </url> -->
    <version>1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <start-class>com.demo.boot.AppConfiguration</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web with Tomcat + Embed -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Optional, for bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have tried many site available on but not able to resolve 
Can anyone help me with the pom.xml for spring boot that support java 1.6?

Comment: post  error screen

Comment: Did you refer [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-build.html#howto-use-java-6)?

Answer (score 6):

By default, Spring Boot 1.4.4.RELEASE requires Java 7 and Spring Framework 4.3.6.RELEASE or above. You can use Spring Boot with Java 6 with some additional configuration. See Section 81.11, “[How to use Java 6](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-java-6)” for more details. Explicit build support is provided for Maven (3.2+) and Gradle (1.12 or 2.x). Support for Gradle 2.8 and earlier is deprecated. Gradle 3 is not supported.

See the link
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-system-requirements.html

Answer (score 2):

Above answer is help but i want to add detailed changes that i made in my pom.xml to resolve my issue.

We just need to exclude jackson jar from dependency and in properties we have to set java version to 1.6.

Please refer my pom.xml to run spring boot in java 1.6.

```
   <properties>
        <!-- <servlet-api.version>3.0</servlet-api.version> -->
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <tomcat.version>7.0.59</tomcat.version>
    </properties>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>            
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

<!-- need to add jackson 2.6 jars -->
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

</dependencies>
```